# How do i extract specific characters from elements in a list in python?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, list

`['PRE user_1/\n', '2016-11-30 11:43:32      62944 UserID-12345.jpg\n', '2016-11-28 10:07:24      29227 anpr.jpg\n', '2016-11-30 11:38:30      62944 image.jpg\n']`

I have a list of string and i want to extract the 'name\n' part from each element and store it. For example i want to extract 'name\n' from mylist[0], where mylist[0] = 'PRE user_/n'. So `user_1/` will be extracted and stored in a variable.

```
 mylist = ['PRE user_1/\n', '2016-11-30 11:43:32      62944 UserID-12345.jpg\n', '2016-11-28 10:07:24      29227 anpr.jpg\n', '2016-11-30 11:38:30      62944 image.jpg\n']
 for x in mylist:
     i = 0
     userid = *extract the 'name\n' from mylist[i]
     print userid
     i = i+1
```

How do i do this? Is Regular Expressions the way to do it?, if yes how do i implement it? A code snippet would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can do it without `regex`. You can try my solution:

```
a = ['PRE user_1/\n', '2016-11-30 11:43:32      62944 UserID-12345.jpg\n', '2016-11-28 10:07:24      29227 anpr.jpg\n', '2016-11-30 11:38:30      62944 image.jpg\n']

def get_name(arg = ""):
    b = arg.split(" ")
    for i in b:
        if "\n" in i:
            return i.replace("\n", "")
```

Output:

```
print get_name(a[0])
user_1/
print get_name(a[1])
UserID-12345.jpg
print get_name(a[2])
anpr.jpg
print get_name(a[3])
image.jpg
```

Also in order to fill the example you gave, your code will be:

```
for x in a:
    userid = get_name(x)
    print userid
```

Output:

```
user_1/
UserID-12345.jpg
anpr.jpg
image.jpg
```

Comment: Nope getting `[' ']` as the output. And i want to do this one by one. For example `a = mylist[1]` where mylist[1] = ''2016-11-30 11:43:32      62944 UserID-12345.jpg\n' and then extract anpr.jpg from it.

Comment: Well, my answer respond at the input you gave. If you have another input please edit your question and i'll update my answer.

Comment: check the question.

Comment: Is it articulate enough?

Comment: Check now. Did it fill your needs ?